# How to add Captcha on GWT project?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, captcha

I want to add captcha inside dialogue box.
This is first time I am using captcha in my poroject

Captcha Widget is not loading.

I used **`gwt-recaptcha-1.0.0.Beta2.jar`** this plugin to show it in client side.
And public key is generated by givinmg URL example.com,

also i included the scripts and its files as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
    src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
    src="/js/jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
    src="/js/sprinkle.js"></script>
```

following is the error come

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: Exception caught: (TypeError) @com.claudiushauptmann.gwt.recaptcha.client.Recaptcha::create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)([string: '6LcTueYSAAAAAHPQtHZgAULhzRiawknYecvkKokU', string: 'recaptcha_div', string: 'red', string: 'en', int: 0]): $wnd.Recaptcha is undefined
```

**UPDATE:**

In browser, when I inspect it with firbug, the console shows an error in retrieving content. Error message shown in firebug console is:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"
```

And I am expecting a code like the following in my html page after running the project, but was missing.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LdeueYSAAAAAKhH5DTUxAv5415DZBgp5cuf0Rmd&ajax=1&cachestop=0.992938555511717&lang=en">
```

When I created a sample project it was there.

**UPDATE 2**
response is:

```
var RecaptchaState = {'programming_error' : 'Input error: Invalid referer'};
```

Comment: I got solved this problem by giving correct domain name for generating the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I figured out what exactly the problem was...

First error message was:

```
 com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: 
 Exception caught: (TypeError)   
 @com.claudiushauptmann.gwt.recaptcha.client.Recaptcha::
 create(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)
 ([string: '6LcTueYSAAAAAHPQtHZgAULhzRiawknYecvkKokU', string: 'recaptcha_div', 
 string: 'red', string: 'en', int: 0]): 
 $wnd.Recaptcha is undefined
```

this was shown only because, from client side the gwt-captcha component try to call the functionality in `recaptcha_ajax.js`, and it was unavailable.

When I inspected more, the client web page using **firebug** it was shown that an error message:

`Blocked loading mixed active content "http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"`

So this was the reason for the first error message.

Now what make my project blocks from accessing this js url is, my project url is `https://domain/index.html`, so secured content blocking insecure content.
see my text transfer protocol is secured ( https), but recaptcha_ajax.js url is unsecure (http).

**solution:**
So in-order to work this out I have to change the unsecure url to secured one.

edit the gwt.xml file in gwt-captcha.jar file.
[***original***]

```
 <module> 
        <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/> 
        <script src="**http://**api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"/> 
 </module>
```

to 
[***edited***]

```
<module> 
        <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/> 
        <script src="**https://**api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"/> 
</module>
```

Thanks.